# docker: calling web service inside Docker

Tags: php, docker

I have in my docker:

- php-5.6-apache - Apache and php
- zrrrzzt/docker-unoconv-webservice - webservice which creates pdf from Libre Office documents
- both containers use network my-network

Creating pfs works fine from shell:

curl --form file=@/var/xxx/documents/output-odt/test.odt http://localhost:3000/unoconv/pdf > /var/xxx/documents/output-odt/test.pdf

But localhost is not recognized properly when its called from my php-5.6-apache container.

It works from php when I use inspected container's IP address e.g. http://172.18.0.4:3000. But this is not a good solution because IP address changes when server restarts.

Questions:

- How can I call web service inside Docker?
- What should be used instead of localhost?
- Or how can I specify url of container?
- Or how can I address my-network?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using Docker Compose, [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the standard setup.  If not, read that page anyways, and then map its concepts to what's described in [Use bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) especially where it describes "user-defined bridges".

Comment: I already use the same docker network in both containers. Problem is when called from php (communication inside docker). localhost doesn't work here. And docker ip address is not the right solution.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I call web service inside Docker?

by publishing the containers port to the machines that use that port.

usually that's done with `docker run -p`, but I'm not sure with your setup

> What should be used instead of localhost?

0.0.0.0 (it's the same as localhost, but includes all interfaces on your machine)

> Or how can I address my-network?

you could try to give your containers access to the host-network: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

Comment: thanks for your answer. I use ports.

sudo docker run -d -p 3000:3000 \
    --name unoconv \
    --net my-network \
    --mount type=bind,source="/usr/share/fonts",target=/usr/share/fonts \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    zrrrzzt/docker-unoconv-webservice

0.0.0.0 didn't help unfortunatelly.
host network doesn't accept ports. So it is not a solution.

Comment: "Containers": {
            "1c8756fc6afdd431f0ef9701950f662d5f8ba5c3a30f4073194c3ce2c69705c8": {
                "Name": "unoconv",
                "EndpointID": "09af921e7097565b3fd46a9abdb3ae470e3429a93ea55a29a545dcfbb8cf1ed0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },


It runs when 172.18.0.5 is used from php:
curl --form file=@/var/xxx/documents/output-odt/test.odt http://172.18.0.5:3000/unoconv/pdf > /var/xxx/documents/output-odt/test.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Now I know where is the problem :D

This command works only when called from other container. In my case from php. It doesn’t work from OS shell and that's why I was confused:

curl --form file=@/var/xxx/documents/output-odt/test.odt http://unoconv:3000/unoconv/pdf > /var/xxx/documents/output-odt/test.pdf

This commnad works only when called from OS shell:
curl --form file=@/var/xxx/documents/output-odt/test.odt http://localhost:3000/unoconv/pdf > /var/xxx/documents/output-odt/test.pdf

Thanks for help